# Make top navbar horizontally scrollable in non-responsive bootstrap template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have bootstrap template which has been made non-responsive using [this guide](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) everything works great. However top nav-bar doesnot scroll horizontally, when window size is smaller.

The example of the issue is [that page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) as well. If we squeeze the window size a bit than the "Link" buttons at top right are not accessible. But the guide itself says:

```
"Any fixed component, such as a fixed navbar, will not be scrollable when the viewport becomes narrower than the page content."
"There is no way around this as it's default browser behavior. The only solution is a responsive layout or using a non-fixed element."
```

Responsive feature is not required, as many of the suggested solutions make top navbar behave as responsive. Just wanted to ask from community if there is any kind of solution to make top navbar horizontally scrollable with rest of the page contents.

Following is current HTML structure

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">.....</div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">.....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just like the example: "The only solution is a responsive layout or using a non-fixed element."

Comment: Right, as there was no other good way to do that, i have to go for non-fixed width. Because this is the browser default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some jquery to add a scroll event to move a div see this http://www.bootply.com/YUULBM3T7h
and the jquery is:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#nav_div").css({"top": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"});
});
```

change your html to:

```
<div id="nav_div" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">.....</div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">.....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was not open to use jQuery for this issue. Only possible work around for me was CSS. As there was no possible solution according to my need i have to use non-fixed width. But this jQuery solution works exactly the way i wanted.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried overflow-x: scroll?  Reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit about `overflow-x: scroll`? That will add some context to your answer, since it is now just a link.

Comment: I think `overflow-x: scroll` will add a separate horizontal scroll for that div which i don't want at all.

Comment: My bad, " if there is any kind of solution to make top navbar horizontally scrollable with rest of the page contents," misread that. Since your navbar is fixed, make it scaleable. Try .container-fluid{ width: 95% or 95vw;